# how to justifyleft the message on dialog?

Tags: android, dialog

Recently,I make a trouble,and I can't resoulve it ,it's that I use the dialog,but the third row text is align center,how can I make it align left?
The following is my code:

```
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

        builder.setMessage("酷夏来临，快来摆脱频繁登录的烦躁感；资讯抓取优化、更新激光推送sdk，如此凉爽！");
        builder.setTitle("提示");
        builder.create().setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("立即升级",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();

                        ApplicationDialogUtils dialogUtils = new ApplicationDialogUtils();

                        dialogUtils.showDownLoadProgressDialog(activity,
                                updateUrl);
                    }
                });
        builder.setNeutralButton("稍后提示",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();

                        moveToGrid(false);
                    }
                });

        builder.setNegativeButton("不再提示",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();

                        saveSoftNewVersionData(activity, saveNewVersion);

                        moveToGrid(false);
                    }
                });

        builder.create().show();
```

[image]

Comment: is this  custom dialog? I create a demo like you said,but it report error,it reminders the textview is null , I don't know why ? I use the Android protogenetic dialog.

Comment: my code should work because this is tested/my project code

Comment: I think your code shoul have this `Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        window.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);` and then `window.findViewBy...`

Comment: No, I'm not sure, I just think so

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("YOUR_TITLE")
    .setMessage("YOUR MESSAGE")
    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    })

    .show();

    TextView textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    textView.setTextSize(25); 
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
```

this might helps you.